# Is there any other country in the world outside the EU that allows this kind of "freedom of expression/speech"?

Tags: religion, freedom-of-speech

There were some Islamophobic incidents that took place in the EU targeting Islam. In France, Charlie Hebdo published cartoons; in Denmark, Jyllands-Posten published cartoons; and in Norway, people publicly burnt the Koran.

In the EU, this is protected by the freedom of speech and freedom of expression.

I have three questions here:

1. What is the policy of the Russian Federation regarding this kind of Islamophobia or other religious phobia?
2. Is there any other country in the world outside the EU that allows this kind of Islamophobia and consider it protected by freedom of expression/speech?
3. What is the status of this kind of freedom of speech/expression after the [anti-Islamophobia resolution passed at the UNGA](https://press.un.org/en/2022/ga12408.doc.htm)?

Comment: The United States definitely does, just as a start. Also, can the mentioned incidents be blasphemous if the jurisdiction where they took place does not have the crime of blasphemy? Islamophobic, maybe, but not blasphemous.

Comment: Many Western countries will not pursue this kind of provocation in law, unless there is also a call for violence against the target group.  Many Western countries' population *also* generally would hold the people carrying out the provocation in contempt and condemn them as rabblerousers.  The problem is that, most of the time this happens, **some** Muslim fanatics, somewhere, take the bait, riot, kill people and make general asses of themselves.  Thus comforting Western prejudices that maybe there was some deep reason to be carrying out the provocation after all.

Comment: And there is no need to quote-unquote "freedom of speech".  That is exactly what it is.

Comment: @Obie2.0 blasphemy does not exist only as a crime.  A blasphemous statement is such regardless of whether there is a law criminalizing such statements.

Comment: @phoog - Did you downvote just for that? Anyway, blasphemy is either a crime defined by a legal system, or the subjective opinion of someone based in their religion. In the latter case, it would not make for a very objective question.

Comment: @Obie2.0 no, I didn't downvote for that or any other reason.  But blasphemy, while it is certainly relative to a given religion, is not entirely subjective.  Consider the law in Germany against insulting people.  If someone insults someone else in the US, it's still an insult even if it doesn't violate a law.  Similarly, if someone insults a religion in the US, it's still blasphemy against that religion, even though it doesn't violate a law.

Comment: @phoog - Religions with a notion of blasphemy tend to define an insult to their own sacred entities as blasphemy, while liberally disparaging those of other religions as false or demonic in their holy texts or even their day-to-day. To my mind, that makes non-legal notions of blasphemy very subjective.

Comment: In the US, if the blasphemy is issued in conjunction with the blasphemer committing a crime against the blasphemed organization, that crime might well be deemed a "hate crime". This can significantly increasing the penalty for the crime. However, a crime must be associated with the blasphemy to be deemed a "hate crime". Blasphemy without any related criminal activity is not a crime. It is instead protected by the first amendment.

Comment: The use of term *Islamophobia* here prejudges the discussion on what is otherwise a legitimate issue (this is particularly serious in the context of Charlie Hebdo, where the cartoons were used as an excuse for assassinations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at least several countries other than those in Europe allow actions similar to the ones mentioned in the question. The obvious example is the United States, which has a fairly broad legal conception of freedom of expression, and where people have burnt [Korans](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/education/florida-pastor-terry-joness-koran-burning-has-far-reaching-effect/2011/04/02/AFpiFoQC_story.html), [Bibles, American flags](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/portland-protesters-burn-bibles/) and more. Laws vary greatly across countries, but I suspect most countries in the world would not prohibit the cartoons, whereas publicly burning Korans seems a bit more doubtful.

With regard to the Russian Federation, at least as of about a decade ago, it was fairly willing to restrict publications [based on the presence of Islamophobic content](https://www.reuters.com/article/cnews-us-protests-russia-idCABRE8900WX20121001). Then again, the same laws against extremism used for this have also been used to [ban certain translations of the Koran](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-russia-koran-idUSBRE98J0YW20130920), so, as people say, your mileage may vary. With regard to burning Korans, there was at least one case where a group of people were [convicted of inciting hatred in a case involving a Koran burning](https://www.asiaplustj.info/en/news/tajikistan/laworder/20160719/12-neo-nazis-convicted-moscow-over-koran-burning-and-killing-tajik-national). But then, they also were convicted of *murder*, which could have been the part that caused them to be declared to be "inciting hatred," so it is hard to say what would have happened in a less violent case.

As far as the UN resolution, it establishes an International Day to Combat Islamophobia, but as far as I am aware, it does not lay any new legal obligations on member states as to *how* they should combat it, so it probably does not change much with regard to countries' laws against anti-Muslim speech or actions. The text of the resolution reiterates several previous resolutions condemning bigotry in general, as well as calling for global dialogue on fighting Islamophobia and condemning any attacks on the basis of religion. In any case, history suggests that even when UN resolutions do call for legal changes, they tend to be implemented or ignored by countries according to the whims of their leaders.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for someone who actively pursued quite a bit of Christianity-baiting, in the USA, you have [Larry Flynt, owner of Hustler Magazine](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1436/larry-flynt).  Lewd cartoons of Jesus were fairly [common in that publication](https://famous-trials.com/falwell/1771-flyntdeposition).

> Q: Mr. Flynt, what is your full name?
>
> A: Christopher Columbus Cornwallis I.P.Q. Harvey H. Apache Pugh. They call me Larry Flynt. And all those historical figures.
> ...
> Q: I thought you told me that everything that appeared in Hustler when you were in charge had to get your approval?
>
> ....
>
> A: That cartoon was commissioned by the publisher at the same time I put **Jesus H. Christ on the masthead of that December issue**.

Never did get convicted, though he did get shot by a [white supremacist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Paul_Franklin), unhappy about interracial sex.

See also [Larry Flynt waged many First Amendment wars -- and not just in defense of porn - CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2021/02/13/us/larry-flynt-first-amendment/index.html)

I also want to show an except from that article which, while it has no legal implication, shows that, yes, societies do acknowledge that freedom of speech *does* have a cost.

> The school paper, the Daily Collegian, reported Flynt's opponents at the university, including the president of a feminist alliance and associate communications professor Mary Beth Oliver, stood ready to challenge him. Oliver had posted on her office door a 1978 Hustler cover featuring a woman being fed into a meat grinder, with the caption, "Who is this woman? ... Your mother? Your sister?"
>
> "I think it's possible to stand up for the First Amendment and simultaneously acknowledge that sometimes the First Amendment publishes things that can be very hurtful," Oliver told the student paper, "and to not acknowledge that hurt is a cause for concern."

##### Freedom of speech isn't primarily *intended* to allow insulting religions.

The *possibility* of attacking religious feelings is a by-product of allowing people to criticize those in power (which in the past has included religious factions).

Why is that important?  Many political protests, by the people, against abuses of power get neatly shut down when vague laws about the "dignity" of governments, institutions and religions are on the book:

- [Russia:  Duma outlined a scale of punishments for anyone deemed to have discredited the armed forces](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-introduce-jail-terms-spreading-fake-information-about-army-2022-03-04/)
- [Pakistan's Former PM Khan Faces Disputed Blasphemy Charges](https://www.voanews.com/a/pakistan-former-pm-khan-faces-disputed-blasphemy-charges/6552901.html)
- [Two Egyptians Jailed For Insulting Military Regime](https://www.rferl.org/a/egypt_jails_2_for_insulting_military/24300146.html)
- [India: making it a criminal offense to “bring, or attempt to bring, into hatred or contempt, or excite disaffection towards, the Government.”](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/07/18/sedition-law-why-india-should-break-britains-abusive-legacy)

Answer (score 1):

In Russia, published media such as cartoons may be disallowed by a court decision based on article 282 of criminal code ("extremism") and put on the "list of extremist materials" disallowed for circulation

Actions such as burning sacred books are likely banned via article 148 of criminal code ("violating the freedoms of conscience").

Both articles were heavily criticized at the time but they are still mostly in place (282 has limited criminal persecution to repeat offenses).

At the same time, the same article 282 may be used to disallow writings by religious fundamentalists (such as al-Wahhab followers) if the court finds that they incite religion-based violence and such.

Comment: This answer is very informative. However, I coudn't accept it because it addresses only one part of the question.